# what is the minimum to install of QGIS for it to work?

Tags: qgis, installation

This may sound like a daft question, but I'm looking to understand what the minimum parts of the install procedure I need to install to get QGIS to work (i.e. can it be installed without GRASS etc?) as I'm looking for the easiest way to roll this product out to a number of users preferably via a packaged installer, so any suggestions/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGIS can be built without GRASS.  QGIS relies on a number of outside programs and libraries.  The bare minimum you need to have to get QGIS to run is:

QT
Proj
GEOS
SQLite3
GDAL/OGR
QWT
expat

This will leave you without the ability to run plugins since you won't have python support. For full tips on building QGIS from scratch see the [INSTALL](http://www.qgis.org/api/INSTALL.html) file and this guide to using [CMAKE to configure the build](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Building_QGIS_with_CMake) of QGIS.